# Multiple Developers working on same IIS Express Port through Citrix

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-express, citrix

My team, is forced to use CITRIX for developing our ASP.NET code, without Admin privileges (so we can't use IIS to setup our websites).
We're all working on the same website; however, for development purposes, we'd like to have our own dedicated IIS Express Ports.
The problem is, by changing the IIS Express ports, we're modifying our project settings; so when we push our code to the source control, everyone else has to deal with the obvious merging problem

I'm wondering if there's a better way, so we can all work in Citrix in peace and harmony without any access to IIS (restricted to IIS Express only) and have our own Port #s without impacting others' projects settings?

(Of course, if we had access to IIS, we all would create our own web-port and point it to our own code).

To be perfectly clear, using Citrix (they all work off of C:\dev{name} folder):

```
John works on C:\dev\John\website
Joe works on C:\dev\Joe\website
Jeff works on c:\dev\Jeff\website

John wants to point his iis express to: web:2222
Joe wants to point his iis express to: web:3333
Jeff wants to point his iis express to: web:4444
```

they all push their code to source control, so changing the IIS Express setting in their project causes chaos

if they had access to IIS, they would all create 3 different web projects in IIS; so project settings wouldn't be an issue.

Looking forward to a solution to this :)
many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option (checkbox) under the Web Tab Project Properties to move the user's port setting out of the project file called "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)". Un-checking this box should allow users to have their own port setting values. [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).