# TFS - IIS Express different port number for the same project run by multiple remote users

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, iis-express

I have a web application  project on a team foundation server.
On another development server, two people connect via remote desktop & open visual studio 2015 & connect to the same tfs project.

Now, When one developer runs the project with debugging, IIS express port For Eg: 2252 gets opened & blocked for him.
This creates a problem for the second developer, because he could not run the project as he gets the error that IIS port is in use.

A way to overcome this would be to check out the project by the second developer & change the port number or Give the second developer another server.
But these are not feasible if my team members expand.

Any solution for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Developers working on same IIS Express Port through Citrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257952/multiple-developers-working-on-same-iis-express-port-through-citrix)

Comment: Hi Abdul Rehman Sayed, any updated on this issue, did you figure out it?

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not related to TFS side, since you have already pull down the source could, it occurs when you run the web app in Visual Studio. Then got a message, saying: `The specified port is in use...`

You could give a try with this solution:

**File** -> **Open** -> **Web Site...**
[image]

After that select **Local IIS**  under **IIS Express Site**
remove the unwanted project.

More detail info and some other ways please take a look at this question: [Why and how to fix? IIS Express "The specified port is in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572897/why-and-how-to-fix-iis-express-the-specified-port-is-in-use)

Comment: I cannot do that as the project is inside a tfs, the moment someone changes the port , the project file gets checked out

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed Are you using local workspace or server workspace?   Using the local workspace, the files are  not affect each other.  [Decide between using a local or a server workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace)